# Date related query

Tags: excel

I am stuck with a very small issue in Excel date function.

If given date is ex. 15-02-2009 then if I need to know the equivalent of that date as of this year, then how to find it?

For ex. given date is 15-02-2009 then ideally answer should be 15-02-2016.

How to calculate this for a huge data?

Many thanks for your help!

Best regards,

Arun

Comment: Please show us what you tried.

Comment: I am sorry but couldn't do much than to add and subtract dates!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the easiest way is

```
=DATE(2016,MONTH(A1),DAY(A1))
```

if the original date is in A1.

Comment: Could you help me learn more in here? Is it possible to add Odd/Even condition for the Original date?

Comment: Thank you for accepting my answer. There are many possibilities - probably worth asking a separate question so you can expand more on what you need.

Comment: Thank you so much Tom. I will raise a new question.

Comment: Hi, Tom! Can I send you a query over an email with attachment?